# Spring property configuration syntax?

Tags: java, spring

I've run across an odd syntax in a Spring XML file:

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="my.thingy.session.SessionFactoryImpl">
    <property name="myPropertyName">
        <!-- WHAT IS THIS VALUE?  -->
        <value>${process.file.thing:propname.server}</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'm not familiar with the syntax of the `${value1:value2}` placeholder - what is the first value `value1` doing there?   Is it a classpath, a package name, a folder name or what?   I've searched for some explanation of this, but it's apparently undocumented (at least as far as I can tell.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm not familiar with the syntax of the ${value1:value2} placeholder

It's <del>Spring Expression Language's</del> `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` fallback value mechanism. The `value2` serves as a default value for `value1`. If `value1` was present, it will used. otherwise, `value2` will be used and in that case, `value2` is just a literal.

```
${process.file.thing:propname.server}
```

In this case, spring first tries to resolve a property named `process.file.thing` from its environment. If it succeeds, it will use that value. Otherwise, the `propname.server` literal will be used.

`PropertyPlaceholderHelper`'s `parseStringValue` method is responsible for resolving the default value. This method looks like this:

```
String propVal = placeholderResolver.resolvePlaceholder(placeholder);
if (propVal == null && this.valueSeparator != null) {
    int separatorIndex = placeholder.indexOf(this.valueSeparator);
    if (separatorIndex != -1) {
        String actualPlaceholder = placeholder.substring(0, separatorIndex);
        String defaultValue = placeholder.substring(separatorIndex + this.valueSeparator.length());
        propVal = placeholderResolver.resolvePlaceholder(actualPlaceholder);
        if (propVal == null) {
            propVal = defaultValue;
        }
    }
}
```

This feature has been described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.html) in `PlaceholderConfigurerSupport`'s javadoc:

> Default property values can be defined globally for each configurer
>   instance via the properties property, or on a property-by-property
>   basis using the default value separator which is ":" by default and
>   customizable via [`setValueSeparator(String)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.html#setValueSeparator-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Thanks.   I still can't find any indication of this in the Spring docs, which is kind of annoying.   You'd think a feature like this would be documented.  Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

`value1` is the property name, `value2` is a default value if the property is not found.  It's useful for preventing exceptions (especially when someone adds a new property without telling the rest of the team!).

Example usage:

```
@Value("${search.engine.url:https://www.google.com}")
private String searchEngine;
```